# Can't connect my database to my src with glassfish

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, jdbc, glassfish

I have make a lot of tutorial.
But i haven't ever succeed to connect to my DataBase MySql.

I have try with the glassfish domain admin console.
As the tutorial said it, i first make a pool, then a JDBC resources. The connection succeed (only on console).
Then i had add Persistence Unit, and referred to the  JDBC resource that i had created.

But when i start to use the Database in my controler, i get this error

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No database selected
```

my code:

```
@EJB
private UserService userService;


    User user = new User();
    System.err.println("date = "+ user.getBirthDate());
    user.setFirstname("pierre");
    user.setUsername("pierre");
    user.setPassword("pierre");
    user.setLastname("pierre");
    user.setEmail("pierre@hotmail.fr");

    userService.save(user); //this make the error..
```

Thus, i have tried in the persistence.xml to add there a new DataSource.

here is my auto-generated glassfish-resources.xml

```
<jdbc-connection-pool allow-non-component-callers="false" associate-with-thread="false" connection-creation-retry-attempts="0" connection-creation-retry-interval-in-seconds="10" connection-leak-reclaim="false" connection-leak-timeout-in-seconds="0" connection-validation-method="auto-commit" datasource-classname="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource" fail-all-connections="false" idle-timeout-in-seconds="300" is-connection-validation-required="false" is-isolation-level-guaranteed="true" lazy-connection-association="false" lazy-connection-enlistment="false" match-connections="false" max-connection-usage-count="0" max-pool-size="32" max-wait-time-in-millis="60000" name="mysql_rmt_rootPool" non-transactional-connections="false" pool-resize-quantity="2" res-type="javax.sql.DataSource" statement-timeout-in-seconds="-1" steady-pool-size="8" validate-atmost-once-period-in-seconds="0" wrap-jdbc-objects="false">
    <property name="serverName" value="localhost"/>
    <property name="portNumber" value="3306"/>
    <property name="databaseName" value="rmt"/>
    <property name="User" value="root"/>
    <property name="Password" value="mypasswordhere"/>
    <property name="URL" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/rmt?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"/>
    <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
</jdbc-connection-pool>
<jdbc-resource enabled="true" jndi-name="java:app/rmt" object-type="user" pool-name="mysql_rmt_rootPool"/>
```

in the window, the connection where successful.But then, i have this error

```
Severe:   Exception while preparing the app : Invalid resource : { ResourceInfo : (jndiName=java:app/sta__pm), (applicationName=STA) }
com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.ConnectorRuntimeException: Invalid resource : { ResourceInfo : (jndiName=java:app/sta__pm), (applicationName=STA) }
```

So i'm pretty lost now.. Can someone help me please?

Maybe i should not start to create a persistence first ?
or my JNDI name is that wrong ?

Comment: Can you post some of your controller code?  I think you have the right idea, that `glassfish-resources.xml` points to the connection pool.